# Weird Object Shape in Solid Mode

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, bevel

My object behaves weirdly in Viewport's Solid Mode, it's shown like this in the Solid Mode:

[image]

But when I render the scene, it's shown well (as it should be):

[image]

It only has a Bevel modifier:

[image]

The object in the Edit Mode (Solid Mode):

[image]

Edit Mode + X-Ray Mode (in Solid Mode):

[image]

Edit Mode + X-Ray Mode (in Wireframe Mode):

[image]

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

Bevel modifier, when applied to the whole of complex meshes in particular,  can mess things up. To avoid this model the shape from a subdivided, 8×8, plane removing undesired vertices/edges. Bevel it, selected vertices only (it's called a vertex group), to obtain rounded corners as shown below. Extrude it when done and remove doubles. 
[image]
Use knife project with the cut through enabled for the rounded holes as the rectangular hole is the subdivided faces deleted.

Comment: Can you please explain it more clear (what exactly should I do?)? Thanks

Comment: I added an explanatory image.